# GC collector using more than specified number of threads jdk1.7.0_51

Tags: garbage-collection, java-7

I work on a cluster computer and I am using the following command :

> java -Xmx6100m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -jar
>   /sw/GenomeAnalysisTK-2.7-4-g6f46d11/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -T
>   DepthOfCoverage -I /a/AID1111.bam -L /a/123.txt -R
>   /a/human_g1k_v37_Ensembl_MT_66.fasta -dt BY_SAMPLE -dcov 5000 -l INFO
>   --omitDepthOutputAtEachBase --omitLocusTable --minBaseQuality 0 --minMappingQuality 20 --start 1 --stop 5000 --nBins 200 --includeRefNSites --countType COUNT_FRAGMENTS -o /a/AID1111.txt

`-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1` should restrict the garbage collector to use 1 core but when I check the details using top command, I see that the garbage collector is using 14 cores.

Can anyone tell me why is it happening and how to solve it.